# Ruby on Rails with Plupload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I am looking for an upload solution for Ruby on Rails where I can upload multiple large image files simultaneously and show the progress to the uploader so they know the files are being uploaded. I stumbled onto Plupload which seems perfect for what I'm trying to do, but I can't find any Ruby on Rails examples on how to incorporate into my application. Any leads, basic examples, or even alternative methods with better Rails documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't any experience with Plupload. You can try [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/). Both allow to upload multiple files and whatever significant Plupload do and require Flash to be installed. In my opinion uploadify easier to implement than swfupload and it is very customizable.

Here is some examples:

1. [uploadify_paperclip_demo](http://github.com/pkordel/uploadify_paperclip_demo)
2. [swfupload_demo](http://github.com/anveo/swfupload_demo)

You can find more examples on github.com. And you need some file attachment plugin on back-end like [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or attachment-fu.

You can find some tips on image preview before form submitting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232008/rails-paperclip-previews). And if you use nested forms, here is [complex-form-examples](http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples). See the [unobtrusive-jquery branch](http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/unobtrusive-jquery). You can add new child on onComplete event of uploadify.

I use uploadify with paperclip, preview and nested forms.

**UPDATED.**

Here are some examples how to use Plupload in RoR:

[File Uploads with Rails 3, Plupload, and CarrierWave](http://neovintage.blogspot.com/2010/06/file-uploads-with-rails-3-plupload-and.html)

[Ruby on Rails + Paperclip + PlUpload](http://www.theroamingcoder.com/node/50)