# How to preview uploaded image instantly with paperclip in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, what I want to accomplish is to allow user to preview their uploaded image before they submit it.

In the controller, i have

```
def index
    @temp = Temp.new
end
```

Since @temp is not saved, can I still use the solution from [Rails: Paperclip & previews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232008/rails-paperclip-previews). If not, can I run javascript or something to run some ruby code?

This is my html:

> = form_for @temp, :url => temp_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form|
>
> ```
>    = form.file_field :image
> ```
>
> = image_tag @temp.image.url
>
> = image_tag @temp.image.url(:medium)
>
> = image_tag @temp.image.url(:thumb)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to preview an image before it is actually uploaded, right? You can do so by using some javascript.

By setting the width and height attributes of the image tag you can simulate a thumbnail.

```
$(function() {
  $('#pictureInput').on('change', function(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var image = files[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
      var img = new Image();
      console.log(file);
      img.src = file.target.result;
      $('#target').html(img);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    console.log(files);
  });
});
```

and the html:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" id="pictureInput"> 
</form>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

you can check it out on [code pen](http://codepen.io/TimKaechele/pen/zFkuL?editors=101)

Comment: I really like this solution. Very lightweight and gets the job done. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Could you also explain how to limit the image to a thumbnail size?

Comment: I added a commented section to the code pen. Basically you can just call `image.size` and you will get the input file size in bytes

Answer (score 0):

this worked in my case:

```js
  $('.file-input').on 'change', (event) ->
    $('.image').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery.  You can do the same thing in modern JS:

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#pictureInput');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let files = event.target.files;
  let image = files[0]
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(file) {
    let img = new Image();
    console.log(file);
    img.src = file.target.result;
    let target = document.querySelector('#target')
    while (target.firstChild) {
      target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
    }
    document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(img)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  console.log(files);
});
```